# Find application password expiration date

Tags: sql-server, security

I changed password of my application on one sql server?
when I am using Login property command I am getting last login date.
I want to know when my application password is going to expired in SQL server.
Please help me.
Thank You all.

Comment: Can you use the LOGINPROPERTY? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Use the `LOGINPROPERTY` function by specifying the `DaysUntilExpiration` property:

```
select loginproperty('YourLoginName', 'DaysUntilExpiration');
```

Reference: [BOL reference on LOGINPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412.aspx)